# Which Predictive Model?

Tags: predictive-models

I'm lost when trying to choose the type of predictive model for my problem. Is it autoregressive model, nonlinear time series, Markov Chain or other? Can Someone please give me some advise?

78, 18, 51, 89, 19, 43, 62, 28, 94, 49

Suppose, everyday I'm given 10 data, and an example was listed above. They're numbers generated by two devices, namely Device A and Device B. Each of them is capable to generate numbers from 0 to 9.

The first number in the data is generated by Device A, while the second number is generated by Device B. For instance, for the first data of "78", "7" was generated by Device A and "8" was generated by Device B. Similarly, for the last data of "49", "4" was generated by Device A, and "9" was generated by Device B.

I want to be able to predict the next outcome variable after the last "49".

I have a total of 300 historical data for 30 day.

From my initial investigation for the 300 data, every device tend to produce repeated sequences. For instance, Device A will repeat the sequence "6-2-9-4" (as in the last 4 data). That means this sequence appeared twice within the 300 historical data for Device A. For another example, the sequence "8-1-9-9" (the 2nd to the 5th data) in Device B appeared twice, too. Each of them produces at least three repeated sequences.

I'd like to predict the next outcome variable after the last "49". Which model is more appropriate?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: My assumptions are: 1. Two devices produce two independent sequences, therefore there're two distinct models. 2. The dependency between the outcome variable and the preceding variables is low.

Comment: Can you post some plots of such sequences?